# jquery date picker not working inside php loop

Tags: php, html, jquery-ui

I have a html form running through a php array loop. It contaisn a date field, and I want to put in a jquery datepicker, but for some reason the datepicker isn't working. here is the markup for the form:

```
$html = '';
$html .= '<td class="main b_width"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong></td>
          <td class="main width2_100">'. tep_draw_input_field('driver_dob', tep_date_short($driver_edit['driver_dob']), 'id="driver_dob"').'&nbsp;' . (tep_not_null(ENTRY_DATE_OF_BIRTH_TEXT)? '<span class="inputRequirement">' . ENTRY_DATE_OF_BIRTH_TEXT . '</span>': '') .'

         <script type="text/javascript">$("#driver_dob").datepicker({dateFormat: '.JQUERY_DATEPICKER_FORMAT.', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "-100:+0"})</script>
         </td>';

echo $html;
```

Can anyone tell me why it is not working?

Comment: How can anyone reproduce the results you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$html .= '<td class="main b_width"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong></td>
          <td class="main width2_100">'. tep_draw_input_field('driver_dob', tep_date_short($driver_edit['driver_dob']), 'id="driver_dob"').'&nbsp;' . (tep_not_null(ENTRY_DATE_OF_BIRTH_TEXT)? '<span class="inputRequirement">' . ENTRY_DATE_OF_BIRTH_TEXT . '</span>': '') .'

         <script type="text/javascript">$("#driver_dob").datepicker({dateFormat: '.JQUERY_DATEPICKER_FORMAT.', changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "-100:+0"})</script>
         </td>';
```

to

```
$html .= '<td class="main b_width"><strong>Date of Birth:</strong></td>
          <td class="main width2_100">'. tep_draw_input_field('driver_dob', tep_date_short($driver_edit['driver_dob']), 'id="driver_dob"').'&nbsp;' . (tep_not_null(ENTRY_DATE_OF_BIRTH_TEXT)? '<span class="inputRequirement">' . ENTRY_DATE_OF_BIRTH_TEXT . '</span>': '') .'

         <script type="text/javascript">$("#driver_dob").datepicker({dateFormat: "'.JQUERY_DATEPICKER_FORMAT.'", changeMonth: true, changeYear: true, yearRange: "-100:+0"})</script>
         </td>';
```

I think `dateFormat`'s value needs double-quotes (`"`) around it as well.